# material-ui Date Picker saves empty value as Date(0) in Redux Form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I have a Redux Form which is using the material-ui Date Picker to save dates. If someone doesn't pick a date and submits the form anyway, the date saves as 1970-01-02. Unfortunately the [documentation](https://v0.material-ui.com/v0.19.4/#/components/date-picker) didn't seem to include any props for handling that and I can't solve it via validation - these fields must be optional.

Is there any option to **force** the component not to input Date(0) when the value hasn't been given? Or should I use another DatePicker tool? We're using material-ui v.0.19.4. I've experimented with using null state which would only alter on change, but it didn't help.

That's how the Fields look.

```
      <Field
        name="endOfPartnership"
        type="text"
        component={DatePicker}
        className={css.fullWidth}
        floatingLabelFocusStyle={styles.floatingLabelColor}
        underlineFocusStyle={styles.floatingLabelColor}
        floatingLabelText={intl.formatMessage(defineMessages.endOfPartnership)}
        fullWidth
        formatDate={formatDate}
        minDate={minDate}
      />
```

Comment: I think you should handle this on server side, as you can never control what the client submits anyways.

Comment: @christopher_pk for some fields Date(0) might be a valid input - for example with birthday fields. I'd just like to turn off this weird functionality that makes DatePicker automatically assign the null to Date(0).

Comment: have you tried the ```defaultDate``` prop?

Comment: @christopher_pk both cases (undefined, null) return Date(0). I think I'll switch to [redux-form's](https://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/react-widgets/) datepicker, as it has a visible support for no input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared there was a problem with a function parsing dates to string.

Someone had a problem with the date conversion and made a very ugly workaround. We switched to moment.js which allowed us to avoid the previous problem and I can confirm that it works perfectly now when no input is provided => the materialUI datepicker works as it should.

Thank you Christopher!

Answer (score 1):

I found where the behavior is defined, just for your reference. From their source code.

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v0.x/src/DatePicker/DatePicker.js

There is this line.

```
value={this.state.date ? formatDate(this.state.date)
```

Where `formatDate` is,

```
  formatDate = (date) => {
    if (this.props.locale) {
      const DateTimeFormat = this.props.DateTimeFormat || dateTimeFormat;
      return new DateTimeFormat(this.props.locale, {
        day: 'numeric',
        month: 'numeric',
        year: 'numeric',
      }).format(date);
    } else {
      return formatIso(date);
    }
  };
```

I guess this is why the date is always "well formatted".

Comment: Therefore we can come to a conclusion it's not going to work with forms. Thank you for your input anyway.